# PostgreSQL on cloudfoundry throws PSQLException: FATAL: terminating connection due to administrator command

Tags: postgresql, grails, cloud-foundry

I have a grails application successfully running in cloudfoundry with H2 as database. I now want to switch to postgresql. Everything works as expected when I run the application locally against postgreSQL.

On the cloudfoundry instance I get an exception during one rather long running analysis, which I perform as a background task (using grails executor plugin). Within this asynchronous task

```
def future = executorService.submit({
    return analysisService.analyzeProject(model, project)
})
```

I get the following exception from the database:

```
2012-11-26 10:27:38,319 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR interceptor.TransactionInterceptor  - Application exception overridden by rollback exception
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Hibernate operation: could not execute query; SQL [select this_.id as id8_0_, this_.version as version8_0_, this_.language as language8_0_, this_.url as url8_0_ from sonar_adapter_configuration this_]; FATAL: terminating connection due to administrator command; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: terminating connection due to administrator command
    at myapp.adapters.sonar.SonarAdapterService.loadSonarConfig(SonarAdapterService.groovy:184)
    at myapp.adapters.sonar.SonarAdapterService.determineArtefactSizes(SonarAdapterService.groovy:145)
    at myapp.project.AnalysisService.analyzeProject(AnalysisService.groovy:46)
    at myapp.project.ProjectController$_analyzeProject_closure2.doCall(ProjectController.groovy:69)
    at grails.plugin.executor.PersistenceContextRunnableWrapper$_run_closure1.doCall(PersistenceContextRunnableWrapper.groovy:34)
    at grails.plugin.executor.PersistenceContextWrapper.wrap(PersistenceContextWrapper.groovy:35)
    at grails.plugin.executor.PersistenceContextRunnableWrapper.run(PersistenceContextRunnableWrapper.groovy:34)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: terminating connection due to administrator command
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:273)
    ... 13 more
```

Any ideas what might cause this?

Comment: You don't need to include signature in your post - your user card is added automatically. Read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chances are you are hitting the configured timeout for long running connections (which can't be changed if I'm not mistaken, as it is here to protect the server from ill formed queries that would consume all cpu/io)

What you may want to try is to slice your long running query into smaller queries and sum up the results (if it's a select)

Comment: It's one service call which calls different other services, thus leaving the db session open (I guess). I tried manually flushing the hibernate session, but that didn't help. Smaller transactions weren't the solution either. Any more ideas?

Comment: Do you have a link where the mentioned timeout is documented?

Comment: Although I have no resource where I can verify this answer, it sound reasonable. Thanks!

Comment: I finally found a solution to the problem. I declared the underlying (long running) service non-transactional and took care of the hibernate session myself (using the withSession closure). That way the session isn't kept open until the service is finished.